# Call a Postgres function via Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.2

I wrote a PostgreSQL function with the return type of `void`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION queryinteriorexteriorcount()
  RETURNS void AS .....
```

The function works as expected when I call it from pgAdmin.
However, I doesn't seems to work when called from Hibernate. Instead, I just keep getting the following exception thrown at me:

```
failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
```

I tried to create a custom dialect and registered my function like so:

```
public class PostgisDialect extends PostgisDialect {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3397563913838305367L;

    public PostgresDialect(){
        registerFunction("queryinteriorexteriorcount", new StandardSQLFunction("queryinteriorexteriorcount"));
    }
}
```

Then i changed the dialect in my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="dialect">at.opendata.hibernate.PostgresDialect</property>
```

and tried to call the function (again) in the following way:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT queryinteriorexteriorcount()");
query.uniqueResult();
```

Can you please tell me how I could properly call this function? I don't expect any return values, I just want to call it - the function would take care of everything else.

Comment: Hibernate is trying to decode `void` into something it can understand and failing. Give it a dummy return value? Or see if you can get Hibernate to discard the results - does it have a query operation to execute the function and ignore the result, like `executeUpdate` or similar? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12557957/398670

Comment: I changed the function to return a dummy integer. Now it works! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fall back to JDBC, here's [how to handle stored procedures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html) and [get Connection from Hibernate session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482731/how-to-get-jdbc-connection-from-hibernate-session).

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.prepareCall("{call queryinteriorexteriorcount()}").executeQuery();
    }
});
```