# How to properly call PostgreSQL functions (stored procedures) within Spring/Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm using Spring MVC 4, Hibernate and PostgreSQL 9.3 and have defined function (stored procedure) inside Postgres like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spa.create_tenant(t_name character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
  $BODY$
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE format('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS %I AUTHORIZATION postgres', t_name);
    END
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION spa.create_tenant(character varying)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

If I run this function inside pgAdmin like this it's working fine:

```
select spa.create_tenant('somename');
```

Now I'm trying to run this function from my service like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void createSchema(String name) {
    StoredProcedureQuery sp = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("spa.create_tenant");
    sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("t_name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    sp.setParameter("t_name", name);
    sp.execute();
}
```

If I run my method I'm getting following error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
```

I'm guessing this is because of return type void that is defined in function so I changed return type to look like this:

```
RETURNS character varying AS
```

If I run my method again I'm getting this exception instead:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
```

Does anyone know what is going on here and how to properly call stored procedures in PostgreSQL even with void as return type?

Comment: How would you call a JDBC CallableStatement? That's all the JPA API wraps around. If Hibernate doesn't mirror what JDBC gives then try a different JPA provider to see how that handles it

Answer (score 8):

In case you are using also spring data, you could just define a procedure inside your `@Repository` interface like this,

```
@Procedure(value = "spa.create_tenant")
public void createTenantOrSomething(@Param("t_name") String tNameOrSomething);
```

More in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.stored-procedures).

Answer (score 3):

In your entity class, define a NamedNativeQuery like you would call postgresql function with select.

```
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
@NamedNativeQueries(
    value={
            // cast is used for Hibernate, to prevent No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
            @NamedNativeQuery(
                  name = "Tenant.createTenant",
                 query = "select cast(create_tenant(?) as text)"
            )
     }
)
@Entity
public class Tenant
```

hibernate is not able to map void, so a workaround is to cast result as text

```
public void createSchema(String name) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Tenant.createTenant")
            .setParameter(1, name);
    query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: this query doesn't compile

Comment: Sorry @AlexG for late response, I have edited Entity code suggestion, but I hope you already found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using **PostgreSQL**, you can, as you've already written, call **any** stored procedure of type *function* in `SELECT` (Oracle, otherwise, would let you only execute functions declared to be read only in selects).

You can use `EntityManager.createNativeQuery(SQL)`.

Since you're using Spring, you can use `SimpleJdbcTemplate.query(SQL)` to execute any SQL statement, as well.

Comment: How to call the function and get the result at controller? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/41864288/287948

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the [`RETURN VOID`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-postgresql-functions-from-hibernate/) that's causing the issue. So, changed the `FUNCTION` definition like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spa.create_tenant(t_name character varying)
  RETURNS bigint AS
  $BODY$
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE format('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS %I AUTHORIZATION postgres', t_name);
      RETURN 1;
    END
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION spa.create_tenant(character varying)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

After you changed your function to return some dummy value, change the stored procedure query to this:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
    .createStoredProcedureQuery("spa.create_tenant")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, 
        Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, 
        String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .setParameter(2, name);
 
query.getResultList();
```

Comment: How to call the function and get the result at controller? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/41864288/287948

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple, just do this:

```
    em.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM spa.create_tenant(:t_name) ")
                          .setParameter("t_name", name)").list();
```

Notice I used list() intentionally.. for some reason .update() didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

- **PostgreSQL**
- **Hibernate**
- **Kotlin**

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_procedure() RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN 'Some text';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

```
val query = session.createNativeQuery("SELECT your_procedure()")
query.list().map {
    println("NativeQuery: $it")
}
```

Comment: How about JPA please

Answer (score 0):

For a procedure, try this:

```
@Procedure("spa.create_tenant")
String createTenant(String tenant);
```