# Is it possible to map JPA entity to stored procedure (function)?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I need to map JPA entity to Postgres function which returns table. 
So each time when I query for this entity, it will automatically invoke this function. Is it possible?
Maybe @NamedNativeQuery can help?

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26122796/how-to-properly-call-postgresql-functions-stored-procedures-within-spring-hibe) maybe?

Comment: Named query in your object is only a shortcut who makes you write the query only once and use everytime you want without write it again

Comment: An Entity is mapped to a table or view. That is all. The results of a FUNCTION can be mapped to a DTO just like any query can be

Comment: i think it would be enough to set the table name to the function, but i am not sure if it will then be called every time

Comment: @XtremeBaumer No, I believe we can on;y put there table/view/materialized view name.

Answer (score 2):

If your function don't have any arguments you can encapsulate it on a view:

```
CREATE VIEW my_entity_procedure AS
    SELECT 'Id:' || i AS some_field, i FROM generate_series(0, 100) i;
```

And then map it to a read-only entity (`@Immutable`).

I agree, that's weird and I don't recommend this approach. Remember that you can use a `ResultTransformer` to transform a *raw* ResultSet in a list of objects (DTO in this case). Something like below must works:

```
public List<MyFunctionDTO> getAllFromMyFunction() {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT i FROM generate_series(0, 100) i");
    Query query = getHibernate().getSession().createSQLQuery(sql.toString()); 
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyFunctionDTO.class));
    return query.list();
}
```

Comment: I already thought about view approach. But my function needs to accept arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the limitations on Postgres but the general rule for **mapping an Entity to an stored procedure** using JPA is [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jpa-stored-procedures):

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
  @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "myNamedProcedure", 
    procedureName = "SP_NAME", 
    resultClasses = { MyEntity.class }, 
    parameters = { 
        @StoredProcedureParameter(
          name = "parameter1", 
          type = Integer.class, 
          mode = ParameterMode.IN) ... }) 
})
public class MyEntity {...}
```

Comment: That's adding named stored procedure query, not mapping

Answer (score -1):

You can use **CallableStatement**

**con** is your **Connection** object

```
 CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call your_procedure()}");
```

if you have parameters :

```
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call your_procedure(?,?)}");
```

EXAMPLE

```
cs.setString(1,your_param);
```

if you wanna get result :

EXAMPLE

```
cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
```

Comment: this has not much to do with the question asked, because its plain sql and neither hibernate nor jpa