# Java List<Integer> cast to int[] throws PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, plsql

I need help with understanding and fixing the following issue. 
I have created a postgresql function for retrieving all events in a specific regions based on regions like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_events_in_regions(regionIds int[])
RETURNS SETOF events AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT  DISTINCT ON (e.id)
            e.id,
            e.event_type_id,
            e.vehicle_id,
            e.event_status_id,
            e.event_title,
            ...
    FROM events as e
    JOIN vehicle_region vr ON e.vehicle_id = vr.vehicle_id
    WHERE vr.region_id = ANY(regionIds);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And it works great when i call it form command line:

```
SELECT * FROM get_all_events_in_regions(ARRAY[1, 3,  6]);
```

Then i have a Spring Boot API that uses JPA for ORM and data persistence.
Inside a EnventRepository i created a native query method like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e.* FROM get_all_events_in_regions(CAST(:regionIds as int[]) e", nativeQuery = true)
List<Event> getAllEventsInRegions(@Param("regionIds") List<Integer> regionIds, Pageable pageable);
```

But i get **PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","**
*regionIds* is a normal ArrayList when i log it.

I also tried without CASTING into int[] but the error was:
**PSQLException: ERROR: function get_all_events_in_regions(integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.**

And i don't know what is going on or how to fix it.
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at these links? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74667627/16034206 https://stackoverflow.com/q/63619548/16034206

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you'd need to somehow register a converter from `java.util.List` -> `java.sql.Array`. The converter would do something like

```java
Array array = connection.createArrayOf("int", regionIds.toArray());
```

Under the hood this `java.sql.Array` could then be set on the `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 0):

Your error strongly implies that its binding in the List by expanding the List into its individual values.

try

```
get_all_events_in_regions(ARRAY[:regionIds]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I solved it.

I had to convert it into a string that looks like this **{6,12,9,4,10,8,11,5,7}**.

It appears that either Spring, JPA, or JDBC somehow, somewhere under the hood casts this string into int[] - ARRAY[6,12,9,4,10,8,11,5,7], which PostgreSQL understands.

So I changed the parameter type from List to String and converted it like this

```
private String convertListToPGString(List<Integer> integerList) {
    return "{" + integerList.stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "}";
}
```

Comment: If this were strings, I believe this would create a security risk as you'd be open to sql injection attacks. https://xkcd.com/327/